# All SeekBar + onProgressChanged + MediaPlayer + MeidaPlayer.getDuration() + Android OS Bugs do not work with me I have "The Ultimate Solution"

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have tried all the solutions on StackOverflow and none solved my issue, I'm looking for the ultimate solution, for the problem, I can solve all these problems with one working code? and 1 software.

Also, I added how to load lyrics using volley, and the PHP backend code.

Answer (score 0):

The Ultimate  Solution is: reencode your video or audio with an encoder that put seek points of the video or audio in the start index of the file and I found one good free software that solves this problem, which is "[Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)"

> Note: mp3 encoding should be 128kb or more before using Miro Video
> Encoder

and the Ultimate code that Will Work for Sure with this Excellent Encoding for audio is (video is the same solution but you change the code to what your video player code is I'm making a songs player with lyrics fragment):

> **Java:**: "SongsFragment.java"

```
package com.emadzedan.acdc;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class SongsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "Debug: ";
private Button playButton;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private TextView lyricsTextView;
private TextView currentTime;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

public SongsFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);

    AdManager adManager = AdManager.getInstance();
    adManager.createAd(getContext());


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "path to: volleyLyrics.php"),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    lyricsTextView = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.lyricsTextView);
                    lyricsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(response));
                    DrawerBaseActivity.DisableBackButtonOnLoadSongDetailsError = false;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            lyricsTextView = (TextView) Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.lyricsTextView);
            lyricsTextView.setText(R.string.lyrics_error);
        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(view.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (!DrawerBaseActivity.DisableBackButtonOnLoadSongDetailsError) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    DrawerBaseActivity.releaseMediaPlayer();
                    DrawerBaseActivity.titleTextView.setText(R.string.all_songs);
                    DrawerBaseActivity.CurrentFragment = "Search";
                    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).onBackPressed();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    playButton = view.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    currentTime = view.findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
    handler = new Handler();
    seekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    try {
        DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.setDataSource("song.mp3");
        DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.prepare();
        DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                seekBar.setMax(DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                Log.v(TAG, "getDuration= " + DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });


    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.start();
                playCycle();
                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            } else {
                DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.pause();
                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        }
    });

    DrawerBaseActivity.selectedItem = 0;

    handler = new Handler();
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer != null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });


    return view;
}

private void playCycle() {
    if (DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    playCycle();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            seekBar.setProgress(DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            currentTime.setText(formatTime(DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
            Log.v(TAG, "getCurrentPosition= " + DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        } else {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            DrawerBaseActivity.mediaPlayer.pause();
            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private String formatTime(int millis) {
    int seconds = millis / 1000;
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    //you can after ? put "00:"
    return (hours == 0 ? "" : hours + ":") + String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes % 60, seconds % 60);
}
}
```

> **XML Layout:** "fragment_songs.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".SongsFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/songLyricsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lyricsTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/TestLyrics"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rudebook"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.90"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentTime"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/_00_00"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rudelight"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/play"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **PHP file:**: "volleyLyrics.php"

```
<?php
    $albumNumber = $_GET["albumNumber"];
    $lyricsNumber = $_GET["lyricsNumber"];
    $data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/lyrics.txt") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo nl2br($data);
?>
```

> Note: the text file of the lyrics is in the same directory as the PHP
> file